# How to make such structures in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to make chemical structure as shown below 
[image]

but i was not able to get the idea how do i achived this so far i have try this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}     %% For \chemfig

\begin{document}
\chemfig{[:-30]*6((N-)-(=O)----(=O)-)}\hspace{-0.55cm}\chemfig{[:30]*6(=-=-=)}
\end{document}
```

below is the output of my MWE code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{-N?[a]-[:60](=[:120]O)-*6(-(*6(-(-[:180]?[a](=[:-120]O))=-=(-?[b](=[:-60]O))--))=-(-[:0](=[:60]O)-[:-60]N?[b]-)=-=)}

\end{document}
```

Note: You can use hooks with `?` to connect distant atoms. Multiple hooks can be defined eg with `?[<name>]`.

[image]